# Fortran unformatted I/O optimization

Tags: performance, io, fortran

I'm working on a set of Fortran programs that are heavily I/O bound, and so am trying to optimize this.  I've read at [multiple](http://astroa.physics.metu.edu.tr/MANUALS/intel_ifc/mergedProjects/optaps_for/fortran/optaps_prg_io_f.htm) [places](http://striky.ece.jhu.edu/~sasha/SOFTWARE/FORTRAN/007-3695-006/sgi_html/ch12.html) that writing entire arrays is faster than individual elements, i.e. `WRITE(10)arr` is faster than `DO i=1,n; WRITE(10) arr(i); ENDDO`.  But, I'm unclear where my case would fall in this regard.  Conceptually, my code is something like:

```
OPEN(10,FILE='testfile',FORM='UNFORMATTED')
DO i=1,n
  [calculations to determine m values stored in array arr]
  WRITE(10) m
  DO j=1,m
    WRITE(10) arr(j)
  ENDDO
ENDDO
```

But `m` may change each time through the `DO i=1,n` loop such that writing the whole array `arr` isn't an option.  So, collapsing the DO loop for writing would end up with `WRITE(10) arr(1:m)`, which isn't the same as writing the whole array.  Would this still provide a speed-up to writing, what about reading?  I could allocate an array of size m after the calculations, assign the values to that array, write it, then deallocate it, but that seems too involved.

I've also seen differing information on implied DO loop writes, i.e. `WRITE(10) (arr(j),j=1,m)`, as to whether they help/hurt on I/O overhead.

I'm running a couple of tests now, and intend to update with my observations.  Other suggestions on applicable

Additional details:

- The first program creates a large file, the second reads it.  And, no, merging the two programs and keeping everything in memory isn't a valid option.
- I'm using unformatted I/O and have access to the Portland Group and gfortran compilers.  It's my understanding the PG's is generally faster, so that's what I'm using.
- The output file is currently ~600 GB, the codes take several hours to run.
- The second program (reading in the file) seems especially costly.  I've monitored the system and seen that it's mostly CPU-bound, even when I reduce the code to little more than reading the file, indicating that there is very significant CPU overhead on all the I/O calls when each value is read in one-at-a-time.

  - Compiler flags:  -O3 (high optimization) -fastsse (various performance enhancements, optimized for SSE hardware) -Mipa=fast,inline (enables aggressive inter-procedural analysis/optimization on compiler)

**UPDATE**
I ran the codes with `WRITE(10) arr(1:m)` and `READ(10) arr(1:m)`.  My tests with these agreed, and showed a reduction in runtime of about 30% for the `WRITE` code, the output file is also slightly less than half the original's size.  For the second code, reading in the file, I made the code do basically nothing but read the file to compare pure read time.  This reduced the run time by a factor of 30.

Comment: Note that `write(10) arr(1:m)` and `write(10) (arr(i),i=1,m)` have the same effect, but both are (very) different from `write(10) arr(j)` in a `do j=1,m`.

Comment: Be aware there is not only a performance issue. With unformatted io each `write` generates a header, so your explicit do loop generates header data for each array element which is hugely wasteful for file size.  ( It also follows you need to be self consistent in how you read it back in )

Comment: The DO loops contain a syntax error, the colons should be commas.  This has nothing to do with the question itself, but could you fix it?

Comment: @tkoenig Fixed, thanks, too much bash scripting in my head at the moment...

Comment: @francescalus Note that tkoenig's solution below indicates that (at least for gfortran), the two are not the same.

Comment: Indeed.  My comment was more about the end effect on the unformatted file rather than how.  That is, the explicit do produces many records.  This is also captured in the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use normal unformatted (record-oriented) I/O, you also write a record marker before and after the data itself.  So you add eight bytes (usually) of overhead to each data item, which can easily (almost) double the data written to disc if your number is a double precision.  The runtime overhead mentioned in the other answers is also significant.

The argument above does not apply if you use unformatted stream.

So, use

```
  WRITE (10) m
  WRITE (10) arr(1:m)
```

For gfortran, this is faster than an implied `DO` loop (i.e. the solution `WRITE (10) (arr(i),i=1,m)`).

In the suggested solution, an array descriptor is built and passed to the library with a single call. I/O can then be done much more efficiently, in your case taking advantage of the fact that the data is contiguous.

For the implied DO loop, gfortran issues multiple library calls, with **much** more overhead. This could be optimized, and is subject of a long-standing bug report, [PR 35339](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35339), but some complicated corner cases and the presence of a viable alternative have kept this from being optimized.

I would also suggest doing I/O in stream access, not because of the rather insignificant saving in space (see above) but because keeping up the leading record marker up to date on writing needs a seek, which is additional effort.

If your data size is very large, above ~ 2^31 bytes, you might run into different behavior with record markers.  gfortran uses subrecords in this case (compatible to Intel), but it should just work. I don't know what Portland does in this case.

For reading, of course, you can read m, then allocate an allocatable array, then read the whole array in one `READ` statement.

Comment: So you're suggesting writing the whole array, even though the values of interest are only `arr(1:m)`?  I think this would hurt more than it helps.  In my scenario, arr is allocated to be quite large because there's a high uncertainty in the value of m, and having to fix this on the fly or segfault, increase, rerun are both a pain.

Comment: It was not clear from the question that only part of the array was actually used.  Mayby I'm just influenced by my own programming style, which is to determine the problem size, then allocate the arrays to the correct size. However, I'll edit the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: `m` changes on each round through the outer DO loop, such that you can't pre-allocate to precisely the right size.  That's what I'd said I could make a variable just the right size each loop through.  I'll try to clarify the question.

Answer (score 5):

The point of avoiding outputting an array by looping over multiple `WRITE()` operations is to avoid the multiple `WRITE()` operations.  It's not particularly important that the data being output are *all* the members of the array.

Writing either an array section or a whole array via a single `WRITE()` operation is a good bet.  An implied `DO` loop cannot be worse than an explicit outer loop, but whether it's any better is a question of compiler implementation.  (Though I'd *expect* the implied-`DO` to be better than an outer loop.)